# Посмотреть значения всех локальных переменных в отладчике

Tags: winapi, отладка, visual-studio-2010

Пытаюсь отладить этот код и понять, почему выход из цикла происходит на первой же итерации, и возвращается значение 0.

```
WORD GetNumberOfSections (PVOID pMem)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDOSh;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTh;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSECTh;

    WORD numOfSect = 0;
    __try
    {
        pDOSh  = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)  pMem;
        pNTh   = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((DWORD) pDOSh + pDOSh->e_lfanew);
        pSECTh = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION (pNTh);

        for (WORD i = 0; i < pNTh->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
        {
            if (!pSECTh->PointerToRelocations
                && !pSECTh->PointerToLinenumbers
                && !pSECTh->NumberOfRelocations
                && !pSECTh->NumberOfLinenumbers
                &&  pSECTh->Characteristics)
                numOfSect++;
            else
                return numOfSect;
            pSECTh++;
        }
        return numOfSect;
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Работаю в VS 2010. Из локальных переменных видны только `pMem` и `i`. Как убедиться в том, что структуры инициализированы правильно и посмотреть значения некоторых полей?

Comment: Вы ставили точку остановки на вашем if потом наводили мышку на ваши переменные? Или в чем проблема? Попробуйте также добавить вашу структуру в режиме отладки в Watch.

Comment: Я захожу в функцию и трассирую до конца. В if навожу мышку на названия полей, и не вижу их значений. В watch эти переменные отмечаются как ненайденные.

Comment: Странно, но теперь значения стали видны. Тогда, может быть, кто-то подскажет по алгоритму, почему поля структуры в if, которые для исполняемых образов должны равняться нулю, ему не равны?

Comment: Ошибку нашел, все ок.

Comment: Поля могли быть не видны (1) если в окне просмотра переменных включено Auto -- переключить на Local; (2) если собрано в режиме Release -- в результате оптимизации "лишние" переменные не видны.